# Align line numbers on jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

1. Problem: Line numbers overlap with code inside the cell. There's plenty of space on the left for the numbers but I have no idea how to align them. [line numbers overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjiCl.png).
2. Context: I updated my theme to make it more comfortable with help of jupyter themes `!jt -t gruvboxl -f fira -fs 14 -nf ptsans -nfs 14 -N -kl -cursw 2 -cursc r -cellw 95% -T -ofs 14 -dfs 11`
   Code in case it is relevant.
3. Probable cause: The notebook extension for collapsing code (functions, loops) + line numbering + font size increases with jupyter themes are all probable fighting with each other.
4. TLDR: How do I manipulate the line numbering extension to align the numbers on the left?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Not a CSS expert so maybe I broke something terribly and it will come back to bite me where I get my injections.
Anyway, I added this to .jupyter\custom\custom.css:

```
div.CodeMirror-linenumber.CodeMirror-gutter-elt {
    left: 10px !important;
}
pre.CodeMirror-line {
    left: 2px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

embedzacharias's way  is very promising, well the offsets still need a little bit calibration.

e.g.  `pre.CodeMirror-line` = 2px would be too close.

Fix:
add the following lines into your `~/.jupyter/css/custom.css`

```css
div.CodeMirror-linenumber.CodeMirror-gutter-elt {
    left: 0px !important;
}
pre.CodeMirror-line {
    left: 10px !important;
}
```

and it will work like this: (the overlapping of line number with code)
[fixed_overlap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNsNf.png)

Issue:
Jupyter notebook theme adapted, line number overlapping with code area

Comment: this idea is only partially successful: if you click into such a cell and the CodeMirror editor becomes active, the insertion cursor no longer appears where it should, but approx. one character to far to the left. I solved this problem by inserting an additional line `.jp-mod-active pre.CodeMirror-line { left:0px !important }` which reverts your change for "active" cells (i.e., edited ones). What a weird hack!